# How to input commands from c++ to gnuplot?

Tags: c++, gnuplot

So this is what i wrote, expecting to get a sin(x) curve in return...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
FILE *gnuplotPipe = popen("\"C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot\" -   persist","w");

if (gnuplotPipe) {   // If gnuplot is found

fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "reset\n"); //gnuplot commands
fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "plot sin(x)");
fflush(gnuplotPipe); //flush pipe
fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"exit \n");   // exit gnuplot
pclose(gnuplotPipe);    //close pipe

}
}
```

but the gnuplot terminal only opened up, requiring me to type in 'plot sin(x)' again. Can this be not done automatically?
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't put a space between the `-` and the `persist`. It needs to be one word `-persist` .

Comment: Also don't send `exit` immediately after `sin(x)`, it comes out as `sin(x)exit` which is not a function. Maybe add a `\n` after `sin(x)`?

Comment: Please read a bit through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnuplot%20c%2b%2b

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! i solved the problem by typing 'gnuplot' instead of 'wgnuplot'!!!